# Get variable by user input and use the variable in form URL

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have a problem with using variables in URL's.  The reason I need to do this in JavaScript is because I can't use PHP (Phonegap).

```
<form action="https://website.com/login.dll?Logon" method="post" id="logonForm">
<input type="hidden" id="curl" name="curl" value="Z2FZ2Fexample.phpZ3FZ26idZ3D<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email'];?>Z26typeZ3D0" />
```

This works, but now I am using Phonegap so I can't use PHP, So I need to get a variable set by the user and then use that variable in the URL (instead of the php echo) I guess. I'll still be using the same form.

So I need the user to enter the info I need and pass that to a variable,

```
<input id="data" type="text" name="data" placeholder="Placeholder" required />
```

What is the best way of doing this in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another attribute to the form

```
onSubmit = 'setCurlValue();'
```

Add code for setCurlValue

```
function setCurlValue() {
    $('#curl').val('Z2FZ2Fexample.phpZ3FZ26idZ3D' 
        + $('#data').val()
        + ';?>Z26typeZ3D0');
}
```

Comment: How exactly do I use this in the form URL? I tried it and didn't work.

Comment: What is your flow? You will add some text in the input box and submit the form?

Comment: I want the user to put in a number and use that number in the curl input, the same as how I did the php echo. @AbhinavRanjan

Comment: Add onSubmit = myFunc();  in form. Inside myFunc get value of data using js or jquery and set value for curl.

Comment: Played around with your instructions and I got it working, Thanks. @AbhinavRanjan